# Android MediaBrowserService customize audio src and meta data

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am building a audio player i have completed all the Songs browsing (UI) activities and to handle audio playback  i am using google sample audio player [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaBrowserService) and i read all the src from this sample and there is class `MusicLibrary` in sample code and it contains a sample list of songs like below

```
public class MusicLibrary {

    private static final TreeMap<String, MediaMetadataCompat> music = new TreeMap<>();
    private static final HashMap<String, Integer> albumRes = new HashMap<>();
    private static final HashMap<String, String> musicFileName = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        createMediaMetadataCompat(
                "Jazz_In_Paris",
                "Jazz in Paris",
                "Media Right Productions",
                "Jazz & Blues",
                "Jazz",
                103,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                "http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/2537.mp3",
                R.drawable.album_jazz_blues,
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ac/Audioslave_-_Audioslave.jpg");
        createMediaMetadataCompat(
                "The_Coldest_Shoulder",
                "The Coldest Shoulder",
                "The 126ers",
                "Youtube Audio Library Rock 2",
                "Rock",
                160,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                "http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/4201.mp3",
                R.drawable.album_youtube_audio_library_rock_2,
                "https://theflagcompany.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Indian-National-Flag-300x300.jpeg");
    }
```

but i am unable to find a method which shows how to add a song in current playlist from other activities for example in my current app there is search activity where user can search any song from internet and i want to add track from this search activity by two different ways **1.** add and play song **2.** only add song in the end of playlist.

Sample code track object use album art image from drawable folder but in my app i need to show album art from internet (Last FM API) not from local folder i tried to edit `MusicLibrary` class and created a bitmap from URI  unable to make it work so this is alos i need to modify in sample code.

Sample code contains only on simple activity where when you open it opens a audio player interface but in my app in HomeActivity  there are some fragments  and a mini  player at bottom now like below

[image]

**Please help me with these two things**

- add songs to player from my code
- use internet image for `METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART`

i just want to merge these two things and i am new to android so no luck please guide me so that i can complete my project. Thanks in advance :)

**My Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    //add song in sample player service from this method
    public void addSongQue(Song song) {

        title = song.getTile;
        artist = song.getArtist;
        mp3Url = song.getSrc;
        albumArtImage = song.getAlbumArt;
        .......
        ...

    }


 }
```

**Sample Code Player Activity** [full sample src is here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaBrowserService)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.android.mediasession.R;
import com.example.android.mediasession.client.MediaBrowserHelper;
import com.example.android.mediasession.service.MusicService;
import com.example.android.mediasession.service.contentcatalogs.MusicLibrary;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView mAlbumArt;
    private TextView mTitleTextView;
    private TextView mArtistTextView;
    private ImageView mMediaControlsImage;
    private MediaSeekBar mSeekBarAudio;

    private MediaBrowserHelper mMediaBrowserHelper;

    private boolean mIsPlaying;


    //https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaBrowserService


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





        mTitleTextView = findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        mArtistTextView = findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
        mAlbumArt = findViewById(R.id.album_art);
        mMediaControlsImage = findViewById(R.id.media_controls);
        mSeekBarAudio = findViewById(R.id.seekbar_audio);

        final ClickListener clickListener = new ClickListener();
        findViewById(R.id.button_previous).setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        findViewById(R.id.button_play).setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        findViewById(R.id.button_next).setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        mMediaBrowserHelper = new MediaBrowserConnection(this);
        mMediaBrowserHelper.registerCallback(new MediaBrowserListener());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mMediaBrowserHelper.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mSeekBarAudio.disconnectController();
        mMediaBrowserHelper.onStop();
    }

    /**
     * Convenience class to collect the click listeners together.
     * <p>
     * In a larger app it's better to split the listeners out or to use your favorite
     * library.
     */
    private class ClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button_previous:
                    mMediaBrowserHelper.getTransportControls().skipToPrevious();
                    break;
                case R.id.button_play:
                    if (mIsPlaying) {
                        mMediaBrowserHelper.getTransportControls().pause();
                    } else {
                        mMediaBrowserHelper.getTransportControls().play();
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.button_next:
                    mMediaBrowserHelper.getTransportControls().skipToNext();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Customize the connection to our {@link android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserServiceCompat}
     * and implement our app specific desires.
     */
    private class MediaBrowserConnection extends MediaBrowserHelper {
        private MediaBrowserConnection(Context context) {
            super(context, MusicService.class);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onConnected(@NonNull MediaControllerCompat mediaController) {
            mSeekBarAudio.setMediaController(mediaController);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onChildrenLoaded(@NonNull String parentId,
                                        @NonNull List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem> children) {
            super.onChildrenLoaded(parentId, children);

            final MediaControllerCompat mediaController = getMediaController();

            // Queue up all media items for this simple sample.
            for (final MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem mediaItem : children) {
                mediaController.addQueueItem(mediaItem.getDescription());
            }

            // Call prepare now so pressing play just works.
            mediaController.getTransportControls().prepare();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of the {@link MediaControllerCompat.Callback} methods we're interested in.
     * <p>
     * Here would also be where one could override
     * {@code onQueueChanged(List<MediaSessionCompat.QueueItem> queue)} to get informed when items
     * are added or removed from the queue. We don't do this here in order to keep the UI
     * simple.
     */
    private class MediaBrowserListener extends MediaControllerCompat.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onPlaybackStateChanged(PlaybackStateCompat playbackState) {
            mIsPlaying = playbackState != null &&
                    playbackState.getState() == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING;
            mMediaControlsImage.setPressed(mIsPlaying);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMetadataChanged(MediaMetadataCompat mediaMetadata) {
            if (mediaMetadata == null) {
                return;
            }
            mTitleTextView.setText(
                    mediaMetadata.getString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE));
            mArtistTextView.setText(
                    mediaMetadata.getString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
            mAlbumArt.setImageBitmap(MusicLibrary.getAlbumBitmap(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    mediaMetadata.getString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_ID)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onSessionDestroyed() {
            super.onSessionDestroyed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onQueueChanged(List<MediaSessionCompat.QueueItem> queue) {
            super.onQueueChanged(queue);
        }
    }
}
```

**MusicLibrary Class where two sample songs**

```
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat;

import com.example.android.mediasession.BuildConfig;
import com.example.android.mediasession.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class MusicLibrary {

    private static final TreeMap<String, MediaMetadataCompat> music = new TreeMap<>();
    private static final HashMap<String, Integer> albumRes = new HashMap<>();
    private static final HashMap<String, String> musicFileName = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        createMediaMetadataCompat(
                "Jazz_In_Paris",
                "Jazz in Paris",
                "Media Right Productions",
                "Jazz & Blues",
                "Jazz",
                103,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                "http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/2537.mp3",
                R.drawable.album_jazz_blues,
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ac/Audioslave_-_Audioslave.jpg");
        createMediaMetadataCompat(
                "The_Coldest_Shoulder",
                "The Coldest Shoulder",
                "The 126ers",
                "Youtube Audio Library Rock 2",
                "Rock",
                160,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                "http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/4201.mp3",
                R.drawable.album_youtube_audio_library_rock_2,
                "https://theflagcompany.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Indian-National-Flag-300x300.jpeg");
    }

    public static String getRoot() {
        return "root";
    }

    private static String getAlbumArtUri(String albumArtResName) {
        return ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/drawable/" + albumArtResName;
    }

    public static String getMusicFilename(String mediaId) {
        return musicFileName.containsKey(mediaId) ? musicFileName.get(mediaId) : null;
    }

    private static int getAlbumRes(String mediaId) {
        return albumRes.containsKey(mediaId) ? albumRes.get(mediaId) : 0;
    }

    public static Bitmap getAlbumBitmap(Context context, String mediaId) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                MusicLibrary.getAlbumRes(mediaId));
    }

    public static List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem> getMediaItems() {
        List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MediaMetadataCompat metadata : music.values()) {
            result.add(
                    new MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem(
                            metadata.getDescription(), MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem.FLAG_PLAYABLE));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static MediaMetadataCompat getMetadata(Context context, String mediaId) {
        MediaMetadataCompat metadataWithoutBitmap = music.get(mediaId);
        Bitmap albumArt = getAlbumBitmap(context, mediaId);

        // Since MediaMetadataCompat is immutable, we need to create a copy to set the album art.
        // We don't set it initially on all items so that they don't take unnecessary memory.
        MediaMetadataCompat.Builder builder = new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder();
        for (String key :
                new String[]{
                        MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_ID,
                        MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM,
                        MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST,
                        MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_GENRE,
                        MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE
                }) {
            builder.putString(key, metadataWithoutBitmap.getString(key));
        }
        builder.putLong(
                MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION,
                metadataWithoutBitmap.getLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));
        builder.putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, albumArt);
        return builder.build();
    }

    private static void createMediaMetadataCompat(
            String mediaId,
            String title,
            String artist,
            String album,
            String genre,
            long duration,
            TimeUnit durationUnit,
            String musicFilename,
            int albumArtResId,
            String albumArtResName) {
        music.put(
                mediaId,
                new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_ID, mediaId)
                        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, album)
                        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, artist)
                        .putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION,
                                 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(duration, durationUnit))
                        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_GENRE, genre)
                        .putString(
                                MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART_URI,
                                getAlbumArtUri(albumArtResName))
                        .putString(
                                MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON_URI,
                                getAlbumArtUri(albumArtResName))
                        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, title)
                        .build());
        albumRes.put(mediaId, albumArtResId);
        musicFileName.put(mediaId, musicFilename);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you got the answer?

Comment: is there any solution